# I have installed the latest version of CocoaPods on my Mac M1 still it is showing dependencies out of date

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

[image]**I have installed the Cocoapods to the latest version which is 1.11.2.
But still whenever I am trying to run the program it is showing this error.

I have tried all the things on stackOverFlow asked by other person still it is showing this error..

Someone  help me out this is eating me out and giving me a headache**

Answer (score 0):

After scratching my head for days, I came up with a few steps that execute flutter apps on iOS without any issues for my M1 Mac.

1. You need to duplicate the terminal and set it up to open with Rosetta.
   [Duplicate Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVGEM.jpg)
   [Open with Rosetta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyr9L.jpg)
2. Once this is done, open your new Rosetta terminal with the root directory of the flutter app.
3. `cd ios`
4. `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`
5. `arch -x86_64 pod install`
6. Go to the root directory again and `flutter build ios`