# Not able to launch Flutter App with correct Cocoapods Version in iOS Simulator on MacBook M1 Pro

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

I'm still new to flutter, so please forgive me if I can't describe the problem quite specifically, I'll do my best:

I followed a YouTube tutorial to set up my Flutter setup with Visual Studio Code, Android-Studio and Xcode. So far everything worked fine and I was able to play around. Also starting the iOS Simulator worked without problems, then it didn't work anymore and I got the following error message:

```
Warning: CocoaPods minimum required version 1.9.0 or greater not installed. Skipping pod install.
CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To upgrade see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.
    
CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
```

After diagnosing with `flutter doctor` I then found that Cocoapods 1.5.2 is active on my system. I then followed the installation instructions to update the documentation and performed all steps, I then also get the message that the latest version (1.11.3) was installed successfully. If I then check the version with `pod --version`, I get again the version 1.5.2. displayed.

I have already found the same problem here and followed all the steps, unfortunately without success. [I have installed the latest version of CocoaPods on my Mac M1 still it is showing dependencies out of date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69986903/i-have-installed-the-latest-version-of-cocoapods-on-my-mac-m1-still-it-is-showin)

I have also tested uninstalling the old version manually `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods -v 1.5.2`, but I get the message `Gem 'cocoapods' is not installed`.

Anyone have any ideas what else I could do?

Answer (score 0):

In terminal run

```dart
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Once this is complete check the cocoapods version

```
pod --version
```

Then try pod install in your project iOS directory

**EDIT**

Try my podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Comment: After running `sudo gem install cocoapods` I get `Successfully installed cocoapods-1.11.3` in terminal. After checking with `pod --version` I return `1.5.2` again.

I also get the error `[!] No Podfile found in the project directory.` after running `pod install` in my iOS directory.

Comment: Pod got corrupted maybe. I shall add my podfile here. You can replace it

Comment: Thanks for your podfile, unfortunately replacing it makes no difference, I still get the same error messages.

I also can't explain why after the new installation of the gems and also the subsequent update I still get the version 1.5.2 displayed at `pod --version`. Also the manual uninstall of version 1.5.2 does not work.

Comment: Take a backup of the project. Then try pod deintegrate and try to install pod again

Comment: deintegrade works so far `Deintegrating `Runner.xcodeproj`
Removing Pods directory.

Project has been deintegrated. No traces of CocoaPods left in project.
Note: The workspace referencing the Pods project still remains.´

pod install still get the same error as before:
´[!] Invalid Podfile file: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1).

 #  from /Applications/Development/marty/ios/Podfile:34
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  
 >    flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
 #  end
 #  -------------------------------------------´

Comment: Navigate to ios directory and run pod init. Then copy the podfile that i gave. Then pod install

Comment: Same error :( `[!] Invalid Podfile file: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1).` There was a Podfile in my iOS directory, I manually deleted it and run pod init, pasted your code and run pod install. produces the error "wrong number"